# Reconfiguring PHP services in FlashBuilder

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have created an android Flex project using Flash Builder 4.6.
Initially the root URL was localhost and web root as /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/.
The application works perfectly fine on simulator.

I have also created a few PHP services for accessing data and tested them on localhost.

Now, I want to test the generated apk on an actual device. For this I reconfigured the rootURl to the global ip of my server and left the web root as is.
But when I run the generated apk with these settings, the application is not able to access the server.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing locally, the root URL generally specified is

> ```
> http://localhost/
> ```

and the directory where services reside is implicity derived from the web root and project settings.

But while performing build for production using actual server, the root URL needs to point exactly to the directory where services reside.

So if the services reside at the following path in the server:

> %some prefix%/ProjectName/services

the corresponding root URL would be

> http:/%serverip%/ProjectName

Note: No need to point to the services directory, since the generated build is already configured to look for services directory in the root URL.